# List of listings linked to incorrect page number in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I want to customize list of listings format in my document and did the following changes in my project:

```
% before \begin{document}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
  \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
  \def\l@lstlisting##1##2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}{Listing ##1}{##2}}
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lol}}%
  \tableofcontents \egroup}
}
\makeatother

% after \begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings
```

After applying these changes, page number for the list of listings in TOC points to the page where list of tables is placed. How can I fix this?

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{TEST}
\author{Abdullah YILDIZ}
\date{October 2020}

\usepackage{listings}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
  \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
  \def\l@lstlisting##1##2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}{Listing ##1}{##2}}
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lol}}%
  \tableofcontents \egroup}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}\label{chp:Introduction}

Interest in exploring the genetic data of organisms is growing everyday.

Miusov, as a man man of breeding and deilcacy, could not but feel some inwrd qualms, when he reached the Father Superior's with Ivan: he felt ashamed of havin lost his temper. He felt that he ought to have disdaimed that despicable wretch, Fyodor Pavlovitch, too much to have been upset by him in Father Zossima's cell, and so to have forgotten himself. "Teh monks were not to blame, in any case," he reflceted, on the steps. "And if they're decent people here (and the Father Superior, I understand, is a nobleman) why not be friendly and courteous withthem? I won't argue, I'll fall in with everything, I'll win them by politness, and show them that I've nothing to do with that Aesop, thta buffoon, that Pierrot, and have merely been takken in over this affair, just as they have."

He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting and fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable, and he had indeed the vaguest idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My Code},language=C]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a clearpage so that the \addcontentsline is executed on the right page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{TEST}
\author{Abdullah YILDIZ}
\date{October 2020}

\usepackage{listings}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
  \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
  \def\l@lstlisting##1##2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}{Listing ##1}{##2}}
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lol}}%
  \cleardoublepage %<---------------
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}%
  \tableofcontents \egroup}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}\label{chp:Introduction}

Interest in exploring the genetic data of organisms is growing everyday.

Miusov, as a man man of breeding and deilcacy, could not but feel some inwrd qualms, when he reached the Father Superior's with Ivan: he felt ashamed of havin lost his temper. He felt that he ought to have disdaimed that despicable wretch, Fyodor Pavlovitch, too much to have been upset by him in Father Zossima's cell, and so to have forgotten himself. "Teh monks were not to blame, in any case," he reflceted, on the steps. "And if they're decent people here (and the Father Superior, I understand, is a nobleman) why not be friendly and courteous withthem? I won't argue, I'll fall in with everything, I'll win them by politness, and show them that I've nothing to do with that Aesop, thta buffoon, that Pierrot, and have merely been takken in over this affair, just as they have."

He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting and fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable, and he had indeed the vaguest idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My Code},language=C]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Better `\cleardoublepage`. Not a problem with the given document class and the current options, but we know that supervisors might have last minute requests…

Comment: @egreg right, edited, thanks.